# Node.js static file looking at wrong directory

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to serve a http page on my server. However the path of the static JS file is wrong.

This is my code that I'm trying to load the static js file.

```
<!-- load angular via CDN -->
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="ussapp.js"></script>
```

This is my server code

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var router = require('./router/index')(app);
```

The static file is located in public folder where it is suppose to be looking for. However this message shows up in the log in chrome

`GET http://localhost:8080/api/uss/ussapp.js`

`http://localhost:8080/api/uss/webapp`is the url to access the html file

Serving : http://localhost:8080/api/uss/

```
// Waiting time Web app
router.get('/webapp', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(appRoot + '/views/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using a relative path you should put a slash at the front since the html page isn't at the root level.

```
<script src="/ussapp.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If ussapp.js is directly under the public folder, and if you access your html file using

> http://localhost:8080/api/uss/

url then this is the main problem for you.

Check this url : http://localhost:8080/ussapp.js, if you are able to access it, then use  in your html file